# Formatting bullet points into an Outlook body using Powershell

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, formatting

I am currently stuck on trying to create an automated email sending system. I'm attempting to format the email in a way where it creates bullet points to list things off.

Code:

```
$mail.body= "Greetings User,

Currently the following are due

#bullet point 1
#bullet point 2

Thanks, Sender"
```

Comment: If you send it as html you can just use: `@"<ul>
<li>BulletPoint1</li>
<li>BulletPoint2</li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what Paxz commented, i found that Outlook is especially cumbersome when it comes to displaying bullets.
One thing you need to do is set this piece of style in the head of the message, right before the `<body>` tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul {
        line-height: 1.5em;
        height: auto;
        Margin:0 10px 0 10px;    /* Capital 'M' */
    }
    li {
        mso-special-format:bullet;
    }
</style>
```

Next, if the bulleted list is inside a (nested) table, you need to do some extra styling, this time INLINE:

```
<table><tr><td><ul style="padding: 0; Margin: 0 0 0 20px;">
    <li style="Margin: 0 0 0 10px;">Blah</li>
    <li style="Margin: 0 0 0 10px;">Blah2</li>
    <li style="Margin: 0 0 0 10px;">Blah some more</li>
</ul></td></tr></table>
```